# Toggle just the class inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have this menu: https://jsfiddle.net/sLu6cja8/1/

And I'm trying to use this javascript to toggle the content of a single section while clicking the "+"

```
$(".singleproject").hide();
$(".plus").click(function()
{
$(this).parent().next('.singleproject').toggle();
});
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `$.toggleClass()` instead

Comment: I've tried but again if I click on one plus it toggles the classes of all the others sections too.

Answer (score 1):

The plus div and the content divs are siblings, so you don't need to go up to parent to access them:

https://jsfiddle.net/sLu6cja8/1/

```
$(".singleproject").hide();
$(".plus").click(function() {
  $(this).next('.singleproject').toggle();
});
```

Comment: You bet, happy to help.